# my windows phone 8.1 application runs on emulator but device (web service returns bad request)

Tags: web-services, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8.1, bad-request

Gives In my windows Phone 8.1 application and using MvvmLight ,

I am sending two doubles to my web service, it  works on Emulator in the following code;

```
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(async () =>
    {
        Geolocator geo = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition pos = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var request = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://..+double a,+ double b, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        BranchList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Branch>>(response);
    }
```

than, I am switch on my phone's `GPS` and `Wifi` but it gives bad request.

Comment: Have you debugged in your device? Could it be that for some reason pos is null?

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you look at your web service to check if you find a difference between the request from emulator and real device?
2) Disable carrier on real phone and try with network, and check again on webservice side too, to see if you find a difference in the request?
3) Another way, with Wireshark you can check your request between real device and emulator (but is more work and complicated than 1 and 2 )